# Remove the range-bar from Google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have created a Google chart and I'm trying to remove the 'Range bar' it seems? (I'm not sure of its official name) but here's a picture. I've tried Googling remove range bar from Stackoverflow but I've had no results.

Any help on how I can remove this is greatly appreciated. What do i target to remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can remove the *legend*, by including `legend: 'none'` in the config options...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('upcoming', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages: ['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    legend: 'none'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```